# Is there a CMDB with a workflow engine out there for managing firewall rules?

Tags: firewalls

I've spent some time trying to find something like a CMDB with a workflow engine for firewall rule requests and couldn't find anything.

We've just started using RedSeal at work and we've came to the realization that our current CMDB (ServiceNow) is seriously lacking when it comes to our ability to verify what the firewall rules for any given firewall should be versus what it currently is.

What I'm looking for is a CMDB where we can actually track all the requested rules for a given firewall.  As it is, there can be dozens or even hundreds of requests put in over the course of a year for a single firewall.  I want something that can spit out a report for a given firewall telling me exactly what rules should exist in that firewall.  If it can then compare that with the running config then all the better.

Does such a thing exist?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That's plenty of things. The thing you can certainly get is an interface to manage firewall, which can calculate whatever the rule makes sense, but not network separation etc. So I'd look at what you have at your vendor site.

Comment: I'm very interested in this. How about mixing this with DevOps - so using the CMDB to manage the management scripts for the firewall - would that help at all? Then lock down the firewall so that only whatever runs the config scripts has access? This is an area I need to get into so I have little experience as yet. Keen to find out more.

Comment: These are good ideas, but I think you missed what I was actually getting at.  What I would like to have is a database that contains all of the approved firewall rules.  Ideally, one that has an interface for people to put in the rules, have a workflow for approval, and then issue a work order to the network team.  Then, when we have to do audits, we can pull the approved firewall rules and then compare them (manually for now) to what RedSeal says the actual firewall configurations are.

Comment: You aren't asking for a CMDB but version control software. Like Git, or Hg. These are used for things like firewall rules and device configs.